# How YouTube website can use autoplay feature function without DOMException

Tags: audio, video, youtube, domexception

I wonder why YouTube can use autoplay feature without `DOMException` because when I tried to use `<audio/>` and `<video/>` tags with autoplay when loaded, It's show an `DOMException` error. I tried another way by set an attribute `playInLines={true}` and `muted={true}` it first, then called `ref.current.play()` and finally unmute it. Unfortunately, the browser isn't allow to play without user interact first by showing `DOMException` error.

When I using YouTube website, I noticed that YouTube won't autoplay until I switched back to YouTube tab, the video is autoplayed.

I searched from internet that YouTube website is built from the framework that load only the element that it needed, the other element won't refreshed.

Is YouTube a Single Page Application. If it isn't, when the user interacted first time on loaded, can the website play the videos forever? (not counted the AFK interruption (YouTube Premium user won't encountner this))

I don't have any knowledge but I guess that YouTube is using the both of `<audio/>` and `<video/>` tags.

Comment: I'm affraid only YouTube knows that and I doubt they share that knowledge.

Comment: I inspect by F12, but they still using `<video>` tag to handle the whole playing.